# Polymorphism without virtual in C++ for multi level inheritance

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism, virtual, function-pointers

I have a situation where I need to achieve polymorphism without vtable. Here is what I am trying to do

- There is a class hierarchy: C extends B, B extends A
- The idea is to declare a function pointer in A and constructors of B and C assign their corresponding methods to the function pointer in A
- With the code below I am able to achieve polymorphism for class C but not for class B.

Obviously I am missing something here. I am not sure if this is even possible. Greatly appreciate any insights into this problem.

I can do this with the below code

```
A<C> *c = new C();
c->BasePrint(); //Reached C's Print
```

but not this

```
// A<B> *b = new B();
// b->BasePrint(); //Intentionally incorrect to demonstrate the problem.
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

```cs
template <typename T>
class A
{
public:
    typedef void (T::*PrintFn)(void);
protected:
    PrintFn printFn;
public:
    void BasePrint()
    {
        if(printFn)
            (((T*)this)->*printFn)();
    }
};


template <typename T>
class B : public A<T>
{
public:
    B()
    {
        printFn = &B::Print;
    }

    void Print()
    {
        //Print B
    }
};



class C : public B<C>
{
public:
    C()
    {
        printFn = &C::Print;
    }

    void Print()
    {
        //Print C
    }
};
```

Comment: Could you maybe show some failing test case?

Comment: This is not polymorphism without vtable. This is polymorphism using hand coded vtable as opposed to compiler generated vtable. I can't see any reason for this.

Comment: Yes, I agree that it is kind of hand coded vtable. I really have a situation where I need to port a huge code base to a compiler without support for virtual functions. Trying to find a smart way to do this.

Comment: @anumalla: What kind of C++ compiler doesn't support virtual functions?

Comment: I think even Tubro C++ which is more than 20 years old supports virtual functions. I do not remember any C++ compiler ever released which didn't support virtual functions. Even the 80s Cfront which was a preprocessor for C supported virtual functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

struct own_type {};

template<template<typename T>class CRTP, typename In, typename D>
struct DoCRTP: CRTP<In> {};
template<template<typename T>class CRTP, typename D>
struct DoCRTP<CRTP, own_type, D>: CRTP<D> {};

template<typename D>
struct A {
   D* self() { return static_cast<D*>(this); }
   D const* self() const { return static_cast<D*>(this); }
   A() {
      std::cout << "A<" << typeid(D).name() << ">\n";
      self()->print();
   }
};

template<typename T=own_type>
struct B:DoCRTP<A, T, B<T>> {
   B() {
      std::cout << "B<" << typeid(T).name() << ">\n";
   }
   void print() { std::cout<<"I am a B\n"; }
};

template<typename T=own_type>
struct C:DoCRTP<B, T, C<T>> {
   C() {
      std::cout << "C<" << typeid(T).name() << ">\n";
   }
   void print() { std::cout<<"I am a C\n"; }
};

void test() {
   std::cout << "Instance of B<>:\n";
   B<> b;
   std::cout << "Instance of C<>:\n";
   C<> c;
}

int main() {
   test();
}
```

Here we have a way you can pass in the most derived class, and if you pass in nothing you are assumed to be the most derived class.

However, there is a problem with your design -- `A` already fully knows its type situation, so there is no need for virtual behavior!  `BasePrint` could `static_cast<T*>(this)->Print()` and you'd do away with your overhead.

The fundamental problem you have is that you are storing specific-type member function pointers in your base class `A`.

A template-less `A` could store pointers to non-specific type function pointers -- say "static" ones that explicitly take an `A*` as the first argument.  In C++11, you could auto-build these functions from member functions.  In C++03, `std::bind` should let you convert your member function pointers to `D` to functions that take an `A*` as the first argument.

Comment: Thanks, This is something I was looking for. But I am still unable to do something like with this solution.

    A<>* a = new A<>();
    A<>* b = new B<>();
    A<>* c = new C<>();

Comment: Yep.  After the code I included a discussion about how to go about that.  The idea is that there is both `A` and `A_impl<T>`, where `A` stores your manual vtable of functions like `void (*)(A*,...)`, and `A_impl<T>` takes methods like `void (T::*)(...)` and stores them in `A`.  How to do this depends on what other features your compiler supports -- with lambda support this is easy.

Answer (score 1):

You are not specifying the template parameter for B in:

```
A<B> *b = new B();
```

as opposed to its declaration:

```
template <typename T>
class B : public A<T>
```

You should go with something long the lines of:

```
A<B<X>> *b = new B<X>();
```

with `X` being a non templated type.

Answer (score 1):

> I can do this with the below code [...] but not this:

```
    A<B> *b = new B();
    b->BasePrint(); //Intentionally incorrect to demonstrate the problem.
```

Well, the problem here is that `B` is a class *template*, and you are not instantiating it. It doesn't have much to do with polymorphism nor with vtables. A class template is just a blueprint (well, a *template* in fact) for instantiating types by passing arguments to them, but it is not a type *per se*.

You should use some template arguments when instantiating `B`. For instance:

```
A<C>* b = new B<C>();
b->BasePrint();
```

And you should see this invoking `B::Print()`. Here is a [live example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/N6QE5%2414).

Comment: It should be `A<B>* b = new B<B>()`.  But that, naturally, doesn't work: `B` is a template, not a type.